# Iterating through nested hashes named using strings

Tags: ruby

I'm having some trouble iterating through a series of nested hashes, and I think its because the inner hashes are named with strings. Unfortunately, I cannot simply change these names. Here is a generic hash of the kind that I am working with:

```
hash =
  "name" => {
  "stuff" => "value",
  "key" => "value", },

  "name" => {          
  "stuff" => "value",
  "key" => "value", },
```

I'm trying to write a program that will print the fields labelled as "name" as well the values, within, when called by the names of their keys. Right now, I am stuck with

```
hash.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  key.each do |stuff, info|
  puts info if category == "stuff"
  end
end
```

but this gives the error that each is not a recognized method for the key, which is, I think, because the computer is treating it as a string due to its naming. Does anyone have any ideas how I can proceed from here (without changing the names of the keys)?

Comment: can you give me example of the output?

Comment: Please edit to make `hash` a valid Ruby object (i.e., `hash = {...}`). Note that a hash's keys must be unique. You can have `hash = { "name1"=>{ "stuff"=>"value"}, "name2"=>{ "stuff"=>"value"}  }`, but not `hash = { "name"=>{ "stuff"=>"value"}, "name"=>{ "stuff"=>"value"}  }`, because `"name"` appears twice as a key.

Comment: The *value* is the nested hash, not the key. You need `.each` on the *value*. You also need to realize that naming your block arguments the same as the strings in the hash doesn't do anything. The variables names don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

As @meager says - the sub-hash is in the value. Try this

```
hash.each do |key, sub_hash|
  puts key
  sub_hash.each do |category, info|
    puts info if category == "stuff"
  end
end
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much, this helps a lot. One follow-up question that I have is what happens if the whole data structure is nested inside a method? How should I go about accessing it to iterate through then, since the each method does not work for method names?

Comment: If the method returns a nested hash (or there enumerable object), then the each will act on the returned hash. So method_name.each works as long as method_name returns an enumerable object.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an array of hashes, and not a Hash:

```
arr = [
      {"name" => {"stuff" => "value","key" => "value" }},
      {"name" => {"stuff" => "value","key" => "value" }},
      {"noname" => {}}
    ]

arr.each do |hash|
  name = hash["name"]
  puts name["stuff"] if name
end
```